# Quick question on integration in Calc II (likely very easy)

Tags: calculus, integration

If I'm taking the integral of h(x) from [a, b] and the integrand is [xf(t) + g(t)]^2 dt, I can just pull out the x term as a constant (after expanding and breaking the integral up of course) since I'm integrating with respect to t, correct?

Comment: That is correct but the $x$ remains attached to $g$.

Comment: After I break up the integral there is no x on the g(t). Also, what is the rule for this so I know in the future? The fact that it was h(x) with x in the input messed me up a little.

Comment: I'd need to see more to tell you.  Your question is very vague.

Comment: I expanded out the integrand, which became x^2(f^2(t)) + 2xf(t)g(t) + g^2(t). Then I broke up the integrals and pulled x out as a constant from the first two. That's fine, right? I am asking, how do I know that I can do this? What is the rule?

Comment: That's OK, so long as $x$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Yeah, so we can do that as long as it's not a substitution or something where x = t^2 or something to that effect?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $x$ is like a constant since you are integrating in $t$ so $\int (xf(t)+g(t))^2 dt = \int x^2f^2(t)+2xf(t)g(t)+g^2(t)dt=x^2\int f^2(t)dt+2x \int f(t)g(t)dt+\int g^2(t)dt$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_a^b (xf(t)+g(t))^2 \, dt = \int_a^b (x^2f(t)^2+2xf(t)g(t)+g(t)^2)\,dt
$$
$$
= x^2\int_a^b f(t)^2\,dt + 2x\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\,dt + \int_a^b g(t)^2\, dt.
$$

Comment: Why does the g^2 integral say from [1, b]? Is that a typo?

Comment: Typo. ${{{{{}}}}}$